# combine navigation and tabbar controller in xcode4 with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode4, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

In my tabbar controller, there is a table with number of rows. If we touch up inside the table cell it leads to another view which has the details of the table cell. But the tabbar disappears. But i want the tabbar to be appear in the navigated view also.

Comment: Im not sure if they way your doing this is correct. you might want to look into building your own tab bar. this link might help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html

Comment: thanks @geminiCoder  i already saw these documentation, I feel better if any example tutorial to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be useful to you.. Im not sure but you can try this. Click [here](http://www.crispinworks.com/ProgrammingFiles/CombiningTabBarNavControllers.pdf) to go.. Best of luck